# Function : PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WORK_DAYS'

Tags: sql, function, for-loop, oracle-apex, procedures

I am trying to create a package that includes both a function and procedure, with the function being called in the procedure. I feel like my code below should work but I keep getting the error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WORK_DAYS'. Any advice on what the issue is?

I also think that when this will run it will return more than one row, anyway around throwing an error? I have used a For loop in the procedure but will I also need one in the function?

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY WORK_ALLOCATION_OVERDUE IS
     FUNCTION WORK_DAYS 
    (P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
     RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        TOTAL NUMBER;
        BEGIN
        SELECT ROUND(WORK_END_DATE - SYSDATE) 
        INTO TOTAL
        FROM PL_WORK_ALLOCATION
        WHERE P_EMP_ID = D_EMP_ID;
        RETURN TOTAL;    
END WORK_DAYS;    

PROCEDURE WORK_DAYS_INFO
    (P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
    IS 
        CURSOR CUR_CRIME IS
        SELECT S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, WORK_DESC, WORK_END_DATE
        FROM PL_WORK_ALLOCATION
        WHERE P_EMP_ID = D_EMP_ID
        GROUP BY D_EMP_ID, S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, WORK_DESC, WORK_END_DATE;

        WORK_FLAG VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
    FOR REC_CRIME IN CUR_CRIME LOOP
        IF WORK_DAYS < 1 THEN 
            WORK_FLAG := 'OVERDUE';
        ELSIF WORK_DAYS > 1 THEN
            WORK_FLAG := 'DUE';
        END IF;

        IF WORK_FLAG = 'OVERDUE' THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reported Crime: ' || REC_CRIME.S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID || ' Work Desc: ' || REC_CRIME.WORK_DESC || ' is ' || WORK_FLAG);
        END IF;
   END LOOP; 
END    WORK_DAYS_INFO;
```

END;​

Answer (score 2):

You created `WORK_DAYS` as a function with 1 input parameter, but aren't supplying it that parameter anywhere in your procedure. You need to pass it the input parameter `P_EMP_ID` like so - `WORK_DAYS (P_EMP_ID)` before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved that error but now I'm getting the error of ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: @user1643333 - because you have more than one record in `PL_WORK_ALLOCATION` for a given `P_EMP_ID`. Not sure why you have the function when you can calculate it in the procedure's cursor; if you do have to have both then you can pass the `WORK_END_DATE`, but then it's pointless requerying the table...

Answer (score 0):

As has been said already, there is unecessary work being carried out in your package. You could refactor to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY WORK_ALLOCATION_OVERDUE IS

FUNCTION WORK_DAYS 
    (P_WORK_END_DATE IN DATE)
     RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        RETURN ROUND(P_WORK_END_DATE - SYSDATE);  
END WORK_DAYS;    

PROCEDURE WORK_DAYS_INFO
    (P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
    IS 
        CURSOR CUR_CRIME IS
        SELECT S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, WORK_DESC, WORK_END_DATE
        FROM PL_WORK_ALLOCATION
        WHERE P_EMP_ID = D_EMP_ID
        GROUP BY D_EMP_ID, S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, WORK_DESC, WORK_END_DATE;

        WORK_FLAG VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN

    FOR REC_CRIME IN CUR_CRIME LOOP
        IF WORK_DAYS(REC_CRIME.WORK_END_DATE) < 1 THEN 
            WORK_FLAG := 'OVERDUE';
        ELSIF WORK_DAYS(REC_CRIME.WORK_END_DATE) > 1 THEN
            WORK_FLAG := 'DUE';
        END IF;

        IF WORK_FLAG = 'OVERDUE' THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reported Crime: ' || REC_CRIME.S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID || ' Work Desc: ' || REC_CRIME.WORK_DESC || ' is ' || WORK_FLAG);
        END IF;
   END LOOP; 
END    WORK_DAYS_INFO;
```

or, just take out the function completely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY WORK_ALLOCATION_OVERDUE IS

PROCEDURE WORK_DAYS_INFO
    (P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
    IS 
        CURSOR CUR_CRIME IS
        SELECT S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, 
               WORK_DESC, 
               WORK_END_DATE, 
               ROUND(SUM(WORK_END_DATE - SYSDATE)) WORK_DAYS
        FROM PL_WORK_ALLOCATION
        WHERE P_EMP_ID = D_EMP_ID
        GROUP BY D_EMP_ID, S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID, WORK_DESC, WORK_END_DATE;

        WORK_FLAG VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN

    FOR REC_CRIME IN CUR_CRIME LOOP
        IF REC_CRIME.WORK_DAYS < 1 THEN 
            WORK_FLAG := 'OVERDUE';
        ELSIF REC_CRIME.WORK_DAYS > 1 THEN
            WORK_FLAG := 'DUE';
        END IF;

        IF WORK_FLAG = 'OVERDUE' THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reported Crime: ' || REC_CRIME.S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID || ' Work Desc: ' || REC_CRIME.WORK_DESC || ' is ' || WORK_FLAG);
        END IF;
   END LOOP; 
END    WORK_DAYS_INFO;
```

However, you do have a problem in that P_EMP_ID appears to be returning more than one row (hence your ORA-01422 exception).